# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: server, php, nginx, postgresql

I have following server cofiguration:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- PHP 7.4.13 (cli)
- psql (PostgreSQL) 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

I have moved my web service based on WordPress from Windows to Linux server. Now,
when I try to load one of the webpages,  my nginx server reports

> 24 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

One of the recommendation I found was to remove the semicolons (;) from php.ini and enable two extensions:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

Unfortuanetly it caused additional warning in php initialisation that those libraries cannot be loaded because no requested files (pdo_pgsql, pdo_pgsql.so, pgsql and pgsql.so) exist.

Do you have any idea what to do to make my webpages visible again?

Comment: PHP extensions are usually delivered in separate packages from the main PHP package; you probably have to install `php-pgsql` package that will provide these files.

Comment: Thanks @raj for your response. I have tried to install php7.4-pgsql but I received comment with unmet dependencies:

php7.4-pgsql : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.8) but 7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Seems that you have mixed up the repositories. `php7.4-pgsql` is probably going to be installed from standard Ubuntu repository, and your basic PHP packages have been probably installed from Ondrej Sury's repository which contains unofficial PHP ports. That repo seems to not contain `php-pgsql`, so you should uninstall the PHP packages you have installed, turn off that third-party repo and reinstall PHP from standard Ubuntu repositories. It's best to avoid use of third-party repositories unless absolutely necessary, as this may cause conflicts with system packages (which you experience).